# How to create multiple broadcaster on red5?

Tags: red5, rtmp

I've installed red5 and I can get 1 broadcaster by connecting to rtmp://localhost/app and then a subscriber also by connecting to same url. I can also connect multiple subscriber to the same broadcaster by entering the same url on each.

My question is that if I have multiple broadcasters, do they use the same rtmp://localhost/app url to broadcast? How can the subscriber select which broadcaster they wan't to subscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that the answer to my question wasn't really in red5 but on the player itself. It seems that the NetStream object's publish method takes its first argument as the name of the stream. And likewise on the subscriber the play method also accepts the stream name.

So to have multiple broadcaster, I'll just have to change the stream name for each broadcaster and the subscriber can listen to which broadcaster through the play method's stream name argument.